# Calculating square roots using the recurrence $x_{n+1} = \frac12 \left(x_n + \frac2{x_n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Let $x_1 = 2$, and define $$x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} \left(x_n + \frac{2}{x_n}\right).$$ Show that $x_n^2$ is always greater than or equal to $2$, and then use this to prove that $x_n − x_{n+1} ≥ 0$. Conclude that $\lim x_n =
> \sqrt2$.

*My question:*

So I know how to do this problem but I don't know how to prove that $x_n >0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: These two: $(x_n)^ 2 \ge 2$ and $x_n −x_{n+1 }\ge 0$ do not suffice to conclude, that $(x_n)$ has limit $\sqrt 2$. These only allow to conclude the sequence is decreasing and bound from below by $\sqrt 2$, so it has a limit **not less than** $\sqrt 2$. You need additional argument to show it is **equal** $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: See also [Proof of Convergence: Babylonian Method $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n})$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82682/proof-of-convergence-babylonian-method-x-n1-frac12x-n-fracax-n) (and maybe other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/82682).)

Comment: I was struggling with this claim as well, but then noticed that it is very easy to prove by induction. It follows immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x_n>0$ then $x_{n+1}$ cannot be negative. Since $x_1=2>0$, the claim follows.

Answer (score 4):

As, @CiaPan said in comments, you need to prove that the limit to this sequence is exactly $\sqrt 2$.

So, here is a different approach to reach the goal.

Firstly, by induction, prove that $$\color{blue}{\frac {x_n-\sqrt 2}{x_n+\sqrt 2}=\left(\frac{x_1-\sqrt 2}{x_1+\sqrt 2}\right)^{2^n}}.$$

So, firstly, for $n=1$, we have, $$x_2=\frac 12\left(x_1+\frac 2{x_1}\right)\\\implies\frac {x_2}{\sqrt 2}=\frac {x_1^2+2}{2\sqrt2 x_1}.$$

Now, use *inverse of componendo-dividendo*, $$\frac {x_2-\sqrt 2}{x_2+\sqrt 2}=\left(\frac{x_1-\sqrt 2}{x_1+\sqrt 2}\right)^2.$$

So, for $n=1$, our claim holds.

Now, suppose, it is true for $n=k$, i.e. $$\frac {x_{k+1}-\sqrt 2}{x_{k+1}+\sqrt 2}=\left(\frac{x_1-\sqrt 2}{x_1+\sqrt 2}\right)^{2^{k+1}}.\tag 1$$

Let's see for $n=k+1$. So, we have $$x_{k+2}=\frac 12\left(x_{k+1}+\frac 2{x_{k+1}}\right),$$ and similar approach to the case $n=1$ takes us to $$\frac {x_{k+2}-\sqrt 2}{x_{k+2}+\sqrt 2}=\left(\frac{x_{k+1}-\sqrt 2}{x_{k+1}+\sqrt 2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{x_1-\sqrt 2}{x_1+\sqrt 2}\right)^{2^{k+2}}[from\;\;(1)].$$

So, for all $n$, we have $$\color{blue}{\frac {x_n-\sqrt 2}{x_n+\sqrt 2}}=\left(\frac{x_1-\sqrt 2}{x_1+\sqrt 2}\right)^{2^n}=\color{blue}{\left(\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{2+\sqrt 2}\right)^{2^n}}[\text{since }\, x_1=1].$$

So, as $\color{red}{n\to \infty}$, the right side, i.e. $\color{red}{\left(\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{2+\sqrt 2}\right)^{2^n}\to 0}$, so, $$\color{red}{\frac {x_n-\sqrt 2}{x_n+\sqrt 2}\to 0},$$ so $$\color{red}{x_n-\sqrt 2\to 0\\\implies x_n\to \sqrt 2}. $$

So, $${\color{fuchsia}{\lim x_n= \sqrt 2}}$$

Comment: This is illustrated further in my answer (not listed), how does this prove x_n >0?

Comment: @SelfStudy, I followed totally different method, it proves the the limit directly. So, in this method, you need not prove $x_n\gt 0$.

Comment: ohh im sorry, i see that now. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From
$x_{n+1} 
= \frac{1}{2} \left(x_n + \frac{2}{x_n}\right)
$
we get, squaring,

$x_{n+1}^2 
= \frac{1}{4} \left(x_n^2 +4+ \frac{4}{x_n^2}\right)
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
x_{n+1}^2 -2
&= \frac{1}{4} \left(x_n^2 -4+ \frac{4}{x_n^2}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left(x_n - \frac{2}{x_n}\right)^2\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{x_n^2-2}{x_n}\right)^2\\
\end{array}
$

From this,
with the initial
$x_1$,
it is straightforward
to show that
$x_n \to \sqrt{2}$
and that the convergence is quadratic
(as it should be,
since this is Newton's iteration).

---

More generally,
using copy, paste, and edit:

From
$x_{n+1} 
= \frac{1}{2} \left(x_n + \frac{a}{x_n}\right)
$
we get, squaring,

$x_{n+1}^2 
= \frac{1}{4} \left(x_n^2 +2a+ \frac{a^2}{x_n^2}\right)
$
so that

$\begin{array}\\
x_{n+1}^2 -a
&= \frac{1}{4} \left(x_n^2 -2a+ \frac{a^2}{x_n^2}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left(x_n - \frac{a}{x_n}\right)^2\\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{x_n^2-a}{x_n}\right)^2\\
\end{array}
$

From this,
with the initial
$x_1$,
it is straightforward
to show that
$x_n \to \sqrt{a}$
and that the convergence is quadratic
(as it should be,
since this is Newton's iteration).

Answer (score 1):

Once you know that the sequence is monotonically decreasing and bounded from below, it converges.

Let $u$ be the limit.  Then $u=\dfrac 12(u+\dfrac 2u)\implies 2u=u+\dfrac 2u\implies u^2=2$.

Now use that $u\ge0$ (see the accepted answer).